# "Do you know what time does the film begin?" vs "Do you know what time the film begins?"

Tags: questions-v-relatives

1. > Do you know what time does the film begin?
2. > Do you know what time the film begins?

Which one is correct?

Comment: Which one do **you** think is correct? Why?

Comment: If I want to ask this question then will I have to make both of the clause interrogative or not?I am confused about it.

Comment: Try and think like this: When you put the two parts together, what is the question: do you know? or What time does the film begin?

Comment: This [isn't proofreading](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/2528/stop-throwing-proofreading-close-reason-at-questions-that-are-clearly-limited).

Answer (score 2):

The second one. The first one already uses the **present simple interrogative** when asking *do you know* (...), so you don't need another auxiliary to construct the question.

If you want to use the first one, remove the first auxiliary and keep the second one. — *What time does the film begin?* —